# Geth doesn't sync ropsten ethereum testnet

Tags: synchronization, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I have 1.10.16-stable-20356e57 version geth and using SSD disk for synchronization.
But it doesn't sync. I'm waiting more than a day... Tried to reinstall and clean data dir, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have same problem?